# How to store ansible_become_pass in a vault and how to use it?

Tags: security, ansible, ansible-vault

I am a newbie to ansible and I am using a very simple playbook to issue `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` on a couple of servers.

This is the playbook I am using:

```
---

- name: Update Servers
  hosts: my-servers
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: update packages
      apt: update_cache=yes

    - name: upgrade packages
      apt: upgrade=dist
```

and this is an extract from my `~/.ansible/inventory/hosts` file:

```
[my-servers]
san-francisco ansible_host=san-francisco ansible_ssh_user=user ansible_become_pass=<my_sudo_password_for_user_on_san-francisco>
san-diego     ansible_host=san-diego     ansible_ssh_user=user ansible_become_pass=<my_sudo_password_for_user_on_san-diego>
```

This is what I get if I launch the playbook:

```
$ ansible-playbook update-servers-playbook.yml                                                                                                                                     

PLAY [Update Servers] **********************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [san-francisco]
ok: [san-diego]

TASK [update packages] *********************************************************
ok: [san-francisco]
ok: [san-diego]

TASK [upgrade packages] ********************************************************
ok: [san-francisco]
ok: [san-diego]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
san-francisco              : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
san-diego                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

What is bothering me is the fact that I have the password for my user `user` stored in plaintext in my `~/.ansible/inventory/hosts` file.

I have read about [vaults](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html#what-can-be-encrypted-with-vault), I have also read about the [best practices for variables and vaults](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#best-practices-for-variables-and-vaults) but I do not understand how to apply this to my very minimal use case.

I also tried to use [lookups](https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_lookups.html). While in general they also work in the inventory file, and I am able to do something like this:

```
[my-servers]
san-francisco ansible_host=san-francisco ansible_ssh_user=user ansible_become_pass="{{ lookup('env', 'ANSIBLE_BECOME_PASSWORD_SAN_FRANCISCO') }}"
```

where this case the password would be stored in an environment variable called `ANSIBLE_BECOME_PASSWORD_SAN_FRANCISCO`; there is no way to look up variables in vaults as far as I know.

So, how could I organize my file such that I would be able to lookup up my passwords from somewhere and have them safely stored?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to create some vaulted variable files and then either include them in your playbooks or on the command line.

If you change your inventory file to use a variable for the become pass this variable can be vaulted:

```
[my-servers]
san-francisco ansible_host=san-francisco ansible_ssh_user=user ansible_become_pass='{{ sanfrancisco_become_pass }}'
san-diego     ansible_host=san-diego     ansible_ssh_user=user ansible_become_pass='{{ sandiego_become_pass }}'
```

Then use `ansible-vault create vaulted_vars.yml` to create a vaulted file with the following contents:

```
sanfrancisco_become_pass: <my_sudo_password_for_user_on_san-francisco>
sandiego_become_pass    : <my_sudo_password_for_user_on_san-diego>
```

Then either include the vaulted file as extra vars like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i ~/.ansible/inventory/hosts playbook.yml --ask-vault-pass -e@~/.ansible/inventory/vault_vars
```

Or include the vars file in your playbook with an [include_vars](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/include_vars_module.html) task:

```
- name        : include vaulted variables
  include_vars: ~/.ansible/inventory/vault_vars
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tested the first solution (specifying the vault file from the command line as an option) and it works!
I have to point out for others to pay attention to the `@` sign, in fact the documentation of `ansible-playbook` says for the `-e` option: «To load variables from a file, specify the file preceded by @ (e.g. @vars.yml).»

Comment: This really helped me in finding a workaround for this.  Thanks :) However, I am pretty sure that this approach will store your password in your inventory file.  I tried this and this appeared to be the case.  However, instead it is possibe to simply pass the 'ansible_become_pass' var in your playbook and then use the --vault-ask-pass when running that playbook.

Comment: You create encrypted file `vaulted_vars.yml` and you reference it as `~/.ansible/inventory/vault_vars`. Is that right? Anyway, I found that I could cleanly reference the encrypted file at the beginning of my playbook using `vars_files: [vaulted_vars.yml]`.

Comment: @andy_roddam Could you elaborate on this: `However, I am pretty sure that this approach will store your password in your inventory file`. From what I can see above, only the names of the password variables are exposed in the inventory file?

Answer (score 15):

The best way to solve this problem is to use host_vars. The easiest setup is to just put the `ansible_become_pass` in Vault encrypted files in the corresponding host_vars directories like this:

```
myplaybook.yml
host_vars/onehost.com/crypted
host_vars/otherhost.com/crypted
```

In the `crypted` files you place the assignment of the `ansible_become_pass` variable:

```
ansible_become_pass: SuperSecre3t
```

Create the file with `ansible-vault create`, edit it with `ansible-vault edit`.

Following the [advice in the Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#keep-vaulted-variables-safely-visible) you need to create an additional file per host that assigns the `ansible_become_passwd` from the crypted variable that has a different name. That way it is possible to search for the `ansible_become_passwd` in the project files.

```
myplaybook.yml
host_vars/onehost.com/plain
host_vars/onehost.com/crypted
host_vars/otherhost.com/plain
host_vars/otherhost.com/crypted
```

where a `plain` file contains something like this:

```
ansible_become_pass: "{{ vaulted_become_pass }}"
```

and the `crypted` file sets the `vaulted_become_pass` like shown above.

All `crypted` files must be encrypted with the same key and `ansible-playbook` must be called with `--ask-vault-pass`.

Comment: Thank you, your approach with the `host_vars` works great as explained at: [`host_vars` files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables) It has only **2 issues**: **1)** the content of `crypted` must be: `vaulted_become_pass: SuperSecre3t` **2)** each file must contain the starting dashes to be parsed as yaml `---` . Fixing those issues it works fine for Multi Host Infrastructure

Comment: the missing dashes `---` result in the Connection Error: `fatal: [otherhost.com]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Timeout (32s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: "
}` because the files are not interpreted as `.yaml` files

Answer (score 7):

After setting up an inventory with your own relevant settings.  These settings assume that you have already set up a rsa-key pair to access your server.

You should be able to ssh into your server with:

`ssh remoteuser@155.42.88.199`

```
[local]
localhost    ansible_connection=local
  
[remote]
155.42.88.199   ansible_connection=ssh    ansible_user=remoteuser ansible_become_user=root ansible_become=yes  ansible_ssh_private_key_file=<private_key_file_path>
```

You need to store your root password in a file (I called mine 'my_vault.yml').  You can do this with the following command:

```
~/.ansible$ ansible-vault create my_vault.yml
```

Simple store your remote server password as follows (do not include the  '<>' tags)

```
su_password: <myreallyspecialpassword>
```

The password will now be encrypted by vault and the only way to view this is to enter the following command.

```
~/.ansible$ ansible-vault edit my_vault.yml
```

We now need to include our 'my_vault.yml' file in our playbook.  We can do this by using `vars-files` to get the value of `su-password`.  We can now create a var titled `ansible_become_pass` which will be passed the value from our `my_vault.yml` file which will allow our remoteuser to su once on the server.

```
---
- name: My Awesome Playbook
  hosts: remote
  become: yes

  vars_files:
    - ~/.ansible/my_vault.yml 

  vars:
    ansible_become_pass: '{{ su_password }}'

  roles:
      - some_awesome_role
```

As we are using vault each time we want to run this playbook we need to use the following command.

```
ansible-playbook myawesome_playbook.yml --ask-vault-pass
```